# PHP file append issue

Tags: php, append

I wrote a script that was intended to modify a text file, but there is an issue with writing text to the file.
The script looks a little unorthodox because I've edited it a few times to try and find a solution. The problem is with the actual append process, I receive the text entered through the echo part of the script so that isn't the issue.

```
<?php
$text=$_POST['typer'];
echo $text;
function write(){
    global $text;
    $myfile = fopen('text.txt','a');
    fwrite($myfile, $text);
    fclose($myfile);
}
write()
?>
```

Comment: So, what _is_ the issue? It just doesn't write anything to the file? Are there any errors?

Comment: You are missing the semicolon after the call to `write();//<--this`

Comment: @Steve I noticed that too, but doesn't PHP automatically add one at the end of the script or at a closing `?>` tag?

Comment: Typo, it's in the actual script

Comment: Well is wasnt in the screenshot. Anyway, please turn on error reporting and edit your question with the actual full error code(s)- otherwise we are just wasting time guessing.

Comment: @Don'tPanic yes, you are right, i had not encountered that before.

Answer (score -1):

You can pass the $text as an argument. No need for globals

```
<?php
$text=$_POST['typer'];
echo $text;
write($text);

function write( $text ) {
    $myfile = fopen('text.txt','a');
    fwrite($myfile, $text);
    fclose($myfile);
}
?>
```

To make it work with globals you need to us `$GLOBALS["text"]` instead of `global $text`

Comment: That's true, and a better way to do it, in my opinion, but in theory it should work with global too, so there must be something else going on.

Comment: Added the globals to the answer

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
<?php
$text=$_POST['typer'];
echo $text;
function write($text) {
    $myfile = fopen('text.txt','a');
    fwrite($myfile, $text);
    fclose($myfile);
}
write($text);
?>
```

Otherwise configure error logging and see if perhaps there is something else going on...

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
    $text=$_POST['typer'];
    echo $text;
    function write($text) {
        $myfile = fopen('text.txt','a');
        fwrite($myfile, $text);
        fclose($myfile);
    }
    write($text);
    ?>
```

In my experience it's often a permissions issue and the file you are attempting to write to does not have the necessary permissions to allow you to open and write to it.